# Display a line of html code base on if/else statement in view.py

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm new to this and using Django. Depend on the if/else statement in view.py, I want the html to display a certain text.

I'm not sure to use HttpResponse() or render(). I have been trying, but none of them work. I would also like to do it without reloading the page

homepage.css

```
.answer {display:none;}
```

home.html

```
...
<label class="answer" style="display:{{ correct}}">Correct!!</label>  
<label class="answer" style="display:{{ wrong }}">Wrong!!</label>
```

view.py

```
def create_request (request):
    ....
    if correct_answer = request.POST.get("answer"): 
        correct = "block"
        return HttpResponse(correct)
    else:
        wrong = "block"
        return HttpResponse(wrong)
```

Comment: Replace `if correct = ...` with `if correct == ...`

Comment: did that and still not working. I think my return method is wrong somehow.

Comment: @KnanhNguyen: yes, you do not render this through a template?

Answer (score 0):

To do it without reloading the whole page you need to use AJAX.
This is how I'm doing it in my app.
I have two `html`files for this to work, one is my page template and the other is a template for the segment of the page that will change after some form is submitted.

#### So my segment template would look like:

```html
{% if correct%}
<label >Correct!!</label>  
{% else %}
<label >Wrong!!</label>
{% endif %}
```

#### The "main" template (template for the page where you show this segment):

```html
...
<form id="my_form_id" data-url="url where you submit your form">
</form>
...
<div id="correct_or_wrong">
</div>
...
```

I have a bunch of forms that can submit data to my page so have a java script function that handles all my AJAX POST requests.

#### Inside your javascript file add:

```
function ajaxPost(form_selector){
    var $form = $(form_selector);
    var $formData = $($form).serialize();
    var $formURL = $form.attr('data-url');
    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: $formURL,
        data: $formData,
    });
};

$('#my_form_id').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxPost('#my_form_id')
        .done(function(data){
            $('#my_form_id')[0].reset();
            $('#correct_or_wrong').html(data);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorT0hrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorT0hrown);  
        });
});

// This is required for CRSF cookie (as per django documentation) 
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

#### In your `view.py` add this:

```py
def create_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        your_form = AnswerForm(request.POST) #Your form class from forms.py
        if your_form.is_valid():
            your_form.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
    # here you need to add your logic that checks if the answer is correct
    if answer == OK:
        correct = True
    else:
        correct = False
    return render(request, 'segment_template.html', {'correct': correct })
```

#### Update

You need to remove the class answer from your lable, or else it won't show...